# Jquery Получить данные из html кода

Tags: jquery

Как можно в html коде проверить наличие такого вхождения

```
<!-- hellotext: Текст -->
```

и если оно есть вытащить из него слово "Текст"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery думаю вам тут не поможет. Обычный, javascript отлично справится с этой задачей. Для поиска в `<body>`:

```
var text=document.body.innerHTML.match(/<!-- hellotext: *(.*?) *-->/);
if(text) {
 console.log(text[1]);
}
```

Если данный тег не присутствует, то match вернет null. Если есть, то массив совпадений, в котором нулевой элемент вся строка (т.е. включая сам тег), а в text[1] первое захваченное скобками соответствие, т.е. требуемый вам текст.

Если в тексте могут быть переводы кареток, то `.*?` стоит заменить на `[\s\S]*?`